# Как создать пользовательскую функцию в Room типа UPPER LOWER

Tags: android, room

В Room (SQLite) оператор LIKE отлично ищет "русские слова" (в unicode) ...но при условии, если регистр слова для поиска и в базе совпадает.
Функция UPPER или LOWER должны привести текст к верхнему или нижнему регистру ...но они не работают.

Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Post` (
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
`nick` TEXT COLLATE UNICODE,
`text` TEXT COLLATE UNICODE,
... 
)
```

Есть запись:

```
id=1 ... nick='Модератор' text='Text'
```

Примеры поиска:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE UPPER(nick) LIKE UPPER('%?%')

%м% - ок
%мо% - не находит
%мод% - не находит
%моде% - не находит
%о% - ок
%од% - ок
%оде% - ок
%одер% - ок
```

Вопрос: Можно ли добавить свою реализацию функций UPPER и LOWER ?

**UPDATED:**
В комментариях посоветовали добавить поддержку полнотекстового поиска (FullTextSearch - FTS). Room поддерживает FTS3 и FTS4.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

```
@Fts4
public class Post {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Ignore
    public int rowid; //обязательно для FTS

    @ColumnInfo(collate = ColumnInfo.UNICODE)
    public String nick;

    @ColumnInfo(collate = ColumnInfo.UNICODE)
    public String text;
}
```

```
@Dao
public interface PostDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Post... post);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post MATCH '*'||:filter||'*' ")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, Post> dataSourcePagedList(String filter);
}
```

Поиск работает но он - регистрозависим (например: ищет по строке "Мод", а "мод" - уже не работает).

Есть совет указать другой токинизер: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716715/android-sqlite-fts-case-insensitive

```
@Fts4(tokenizer = FtsOptions.TOKENIZER_UNICODE61)
public class Post {
...
}
```

Но после указания этого токинизера, приложение перестало запускаться на эмуляторе.

Еще один минус FTS в том, что нельзя указывать индексы (кроме rowid) а следовательно и уникальность поля, поэтому в методе insert:

```
@Dao
public interface PostDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Post... post);
```

не будет конфликта, и строка в базе будет не перезаписана (OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) а добавлена новая. Т.е. перед записью в базу нужно добавить какой-нибудь дополнительный id и проверять по нему наличие точно такой же строки что-бы не сделать дубль.

Что интересно, update также выдает ошибку для FTS таблицы - метод работает только в том случае если есть уникальный главный индекс (@PrimaryKey), а он у нас игнорируется (@Ignore)

Comment: SQLite User Manual: The lower(X) and upper(X) functions returns a copy of string X with all ASCII characters converted to lower/upper case. The default built-in functions works for ASCII characters only. To do case conversions on non-ASCII characters, load the [ICU extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/dir?ci=b02fdc09c838f355&name=ext/icu).

Comment: Я бы вообще использовал `FullTextSearch` - да в ней есть свои особенности, но там и поиск выполняется в разы быстрее (по сравнению с `LIKE`), и можно сразу хранить все слова в верхнем/нижнем регистре. Останется только весь текст с поля для ввода перевести в нужный регистр (программным путем на лету) - и никаких проблем с поиском не будет.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Это тоже модуль подцеплять (FTS3, FTS4 или FTS5).

Comment: @Akina, FTS3, FTS4 вроде как "из коробки" поддерживаются: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Fts4 .

Comment: Есть ещё "топорный" вариант: дублировать текстовую колонку дополнительной, куда писать lower-case версию. Выборку, соответственно, делать по этой колонке, переводя запрос так же в нижний регистр.

Comment: Так уже делал в других проектах и искал через LIKE, но это дублирование данных в базе. Другой вариант: вытаскивать все записи и фильтровать уже java методами. Но у меня PagedList.